# Why to use := in Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

Why to use ":="? What difference between ":=" and "=" ?
For example of build.sbt:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "XYZ",
  version := "1.0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
  libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.11",
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.0",
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
)
```

...

Is it same:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization = "XYZ",
  version = "1.0.1",
  scalaVersion = "2.11.8",
  libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.11",
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.0",
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Question was closed.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The questioner is asking about sbt, this has a specific meaning for :=. The question referred to talks in general terms. The question does refer to sbt in the comments, but this may not be sufficient.